# Handle array value error from edittext android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I write a code for showing map marker in maps activity. When I want to search some array value in `EditText` and I input wrong value I want to show error message here is my `btncari.onClickListener`.

```
btncari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (   editcari.getText().toString().isEmpty()
            || editcari.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
            Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "Masukkan Nama Wisata", duration).show();
        } else {
            for(int i=0; i < nama.length; i++) {
                if (nama[i].toLowerCase().contains(editcari.getText().toString())) {
                    marker.remove();
                    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i])).title(nama[i]).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_wisata)));
                    CameraPosition campos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                                .target(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i]))
                                                .zoom(18)
                                                .build();
                    CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(campos);
                    myMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

also I've tried with `Arrays` like this

```
if (Arrays.asList(nama).contains(editcari.getText().toString())) {
    Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "welcome", duration).show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "Error", duration).show();
}
```

The difference is when I use `Arrays` it will always show `"Error"` eventhough I input the right value from array. So when I put right value on editsearch it will zoom to marker that I typed. the problem is the `"error message"` is still keep showing.

I put `if Arrays.asList` above the `if (editcari.getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (nama[i].contains(editcari.getText().toString())){
 //Your code
}
```

instead of

```
if (nama[i].toLowerCase().contains(editcari.getText().toString())){
//Your code
}
```

Other wise you can create a method to check the edit text input contains in your array list

```
boolean checkArrayList(String[] list, String input) {
    for (String item : list) {
        if (item.equals(input)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use it

```
if (checkArrayList(nama, editcari.getText().toString())) {
    Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "welcome", duration).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "Error", duration).show();
}
```

Comment: i have followed all of your instruction but now the issue is `worng 1st argument type found java.lang.string[], required java.util.arraylist<java.lang.string>` the error show when i type  `if (checkArrayList(nama`

Comment: Code modified, check now

Comment: it will show error message, and now the issue is i always get error part everytime i press search, it's only toast message that show error but the apps it run perfectly